# How to use sympy.physics.quantum Operator?

Tags: sympy, physics

I wanted to show that the commutator of the position of momentum operator equals to i time hbar using sympy,

[image: 1]

However, I couldn't get sympy to simplify the output to my desired format using `qapply()`, `simplify()`, or `expand()`.

```
# https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/quantum/operator.html

from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.quantum import *

x, hbar, L = symbols("x hbar L")
psi = symbols("psi", cls=Function)

xhat = DifferentialOperator(x * psi(x), psi(x))
phat = DifferentialOperator(-I * hbar * Derivative(psi(x), x), psi(x))

w = Wavefunction(sqrt(2/L) * sin(pi*x/L), x)

qapply((xhat * phat - phat * xhat) * w)
```

[image: 2]

The answer is correct, but not simplified. How should get sympy to show what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know other ways. But the following worked out for me :

```
qapply(xhat * phat*w).expr - qapply( phat * xhat* w).expr)
```

[image: 1]